# Why can't I see the page content in the browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firebug

I am not sure what is the problem, but my CSS is not working and I am not able to figure out what is the exact problem as I am new to CSS. I have tried the code on Chrome and Firefox and need someone to explain what is the real issue.

This is a Chrome screenshot and when I am inspecting the element then it highlights the `<div>` on the browser, but it is not visible.

[image: Chrome Browser]

This screenshot is from Firefox and I am using Firebug, but the interesting thing is all the content, which is not visible on the browser, has a different color (grey) than the content visible on the browser.

[image: Firefox Browser]

Can anyone explain me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pale display within Firebug indicates that the element is not visible.
[According to the Firebug wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Node_View) this can have different reasons:

> Faintly displayed elements mean they are not visible inside the page. That is e.g. when the CSS style `display: none` is applied to the element or the element doesn't have any dimensions.

So it looks like the ancestor `<div>` with `id` `ebBannerDiv_...` is hidden (meaning it's `offsetWidth` and/or `offsetHeight` DOM property is `0`) and therefore all its children are hidden, too.

It may be related to `font-size` and `line-height` being set to `0px` for that `<div>`.

For further investigation you can check the dimensions and visibility of that element via the [*Layout* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Layout_Side_Panel). If you see there that `display` is set to `none` or it's width or height are `0`, you can then investigate further by checking the style trace for the `width`, `height`, `display`, `font-size` and `line-height` properties within the [*Computed* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Computed_Side_Panel).